# PHP is_numeric not working with array values

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I'm attempting to skip over the first few rows in a CSV file. In the rest of the rows, the first column is an ordinal - 1, 2, 3, etc. But for some reason, using is_numeric is completely failing. I thought it might be the quotes, but the test array in the manual has quotes and it prints the answer out correctly.

After opening and checking for $afile...

```
    while (($row = fgetcsv($afile)) !== FALSE) {
        // first three rows don't have numbers in first column
        if (is_numeric($row[0]))
            print "<tr><td>{$row[7]}</td></tr>";
        else
           print "not numeric: {$row[0]}<br/>";
   }
```

EVERYTHING comes up as "Not Numeric"!

When I print_r the array, there are still quotes in the column, so I tried running str_replace to strip the quotes and is_numeric *still* comes up as false all of the time...

completely baffled, hope someone can help and I hope it's just a silly "coding at midnight" problem...

[edited]

Okay, as I suspected it's something with the data, but I couldn't see anything wrong. When I went to "show invisibles" in BBEdit, I get an upside down question mark between *every single character*. See:

[image]

So.. that's strange. Assuming I'm going to get these invisibles all of the time until I can figure out the exported data.. can PHP do anything to clean the data? Maybe a charset issue?

[edited again] Thanks to martinstoeckli, I converted the data with mb_convert_string and is_numeric now returns correctly.

Comment: what does your data look like?

Comment: instead of `is_numeric` use `preg_match` since fgetcsv reads cell value as string

Comment: Poonam, yes that seems to work, but why *doesn't* is_numeric work? It should read numbers with quotes as numbers, right?

Comment: chovy, here's a screenshot: http://imgur.com/4lq1Z (In this case, I put all the rows into another nested array because I needed to check for some strange characters, but I run the test on the row itself.)

Comment: what are the values in the 1st column of CSV?

Comment: Like I said, the first three rows contain descriptive text and the header row, the rest are data. The first column just contains 1,2,3,etc. but with quotes wrapped around them.

Comment: the question-mark thing make it sound like a character encoding issue. The fgetcsv manual page has hints for reading different encoding types.

Comment: It looks, as if your file contains Unicode data (2 bytes per character). I would try to convert the unicode string to uft-8, before checking with `is_numeric()`. An untested example: `mb_convert_encoding($row[0],'utf8','utf-16')`.

Comment: AHA Thank you martin! Yes, that fixes the data issue, and is_numeric now works.

Answer (score 2):

A very easy alternative to is_numeric is to check if you're checking for int is:

```
if ($row[0] == (string)(int)($row[0]))
```

or if you're worried about the possibility of trailing spaces also check for `strlen($row[0]) == strlen((int)$row[0])`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps:

```
settype($row[0], "int");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot, the csv file is a Unicode file with UTF-16 encoding. Such files use 2 bytes for each character. If you convert the content to UTF-8 you should be able to treat the strings normally, of course this will apply to all variables read from the file (not only the first number).

```
$rowNumber = mb_convert_encoding($row[0],'utf8','utf-16');
if (is_numeric($rowNumber))
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do `is_numeric((string)(int)$content);`